# Make parent items in nav-menu non-hyperlinks

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In my php generated nav-menu I'd like to make parent items unclickable and not related to a page. I just want them to reveal children when hovered.

PHP code generating the nav-menu:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&title_li='); ?>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check this. With `depth`.

```
<?php
global $post;
wp_list_pages( array(
    // Only pages that are children of the current page
    'child_of' => $post->ID,
    // Only show one level of hierarchy
    'depth' => 1
) );
?>
```

so:

```
<?php
function removeParentCatLinks() {
   $cats = wp_list_categories('echo=0&title_li');
   $cats = explode("</li>", $cats);
   $count = 0;

foreach($cats as $cat) {

  if(strstr($cat,"<ul class='children'>")) {
  $cat = explode("<ul class='children'>", $cat);
  $cat[0] = str_replace('</a>','',$cat[0]);
  $cat[0] = preg_replace('/\<a(.*)\>/','',$cat[0]);
  $cat = implode("<ul class='children'>", $cat);
}

  $cats[$count] = $cat;
  $count++;
}

$cats = implode('</li>',$cats);
echo $cats;

}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! If I get this correctly, those pages won't be displayed? However I do want them to show up just not with an hyperlink.

Comment: Do you use it as a menu? If yes, why won't you create a `custom link` in wordpress and then edit the link and remove the URL, or I edited the above answer.

Comment: Actually I created a theme from scratch and I can't have access to the wp page where I can create a custom link. Just tried your edited answer which looks exactly like what I want. Unfortunately my page can't be loaded anymore. I put it right above my php code, should it go somewhere else?Thanks so much, seeing the end of the tunnel, finally!

Comment: There were some errors in my code, check now please. Add the code in `functions.php`. Now just replace your wp_list_pages(); function with removeParentLinks();

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working :( Put your code in a functions.php file then this   <?php removeParentCatLinks('sort_column=menu_order&title_li='); ?> to the html file. Am I missing something? Thanks a lot for your nice help!

Comment: It doesn't work :/ Somehow this line '$cats = wp_list_categories('echo=0&title_li');' does not retrieve the code.. can you please help? Highly appreciated! Thanks!!